# Norm is sup of inner products (proof).

Tags: vector-spaces, hilbert-spaces, normed-spaces, supremum-and-infimum

Let $V$ be a vector space with an inner product $\langle.,. \rangle$ and associated norm $|| . ||$ Then:

[image]

Could I have a proof of this fact?

Comment: $\mathbf{v} = 0$ is direct. For other $\mathbf{v}$, a special $\mathbf{w}$ gives one direction, and Cauchy-Bun'akovskij-Schwarz the other.

Comment: Shouldn't the constraint be $\|w\| <= \|v\|$ ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since $\Vert \cdot \Vert$ is the induced norm, we have $\Vert v \vert = \sqrt{\langle v,v \rangle}$.

If $v = 0$, then the inequality $$\Vert v \Vert \leq \sup \left\{ \langle v,w \rangle \, : \, w \in V, \Vert w \Vert = 1 \right\} $$
is trivial, so assume $0 \neq v \in V$. Note that for $w := \frac{v}{\Vert v \Vert}$ we have $\Vert w \Vert = 1$. So we calculate $$\begin{align*}\Vert v \Vert^2 &= \langle v, v \rangle = \Vert v \Vert \left\langle v, \frac{v}{\Vert v \Vert } \right\rangle = \Vert v \Vert \langle v, w \rangle \\ &\leq \Vert v \Vert \cdot \sup \left\{ \langle v,w \rangle \, : \, w \in V, \Vert w \Vert = 1 \right\} \; ,\end{align*}$$
which gives us 
$$\Vert v \Vert \leq \sup \left\{ \langle v,w \rangle \, : \, w \in V, \Vert w \Vert = 1 \right\} \; .$$

For the other direction, we know by the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, that 
$$ \vert \langle v,w \rangle \vert \leq \Vert v \Vert \Vert w \Vert \quad \text{for all } v,w \in V \; ,$$
so we deduce that 
$$\langle v,w \rangle \leq \Vert v \Vert  \quad \text{for all $v,w \in V$ with $\Vert w \Vert = 1$} \; ,$$
and it follows that 
$$\sup \left\{ \langle v,w \rangle \, : \, w \in V, \Vert w \Vert = 1 \right\} \leq \Vert v \Vert \; .$$

This shows the equality $$\Vert v \Vert = \sup \left\{ \langle v,w \rangle \, : \, w \in V, \Vert w \Vert = 1 \right\} \quad \text{for each $v \in V$} \; .$$

Answer (score 1):

By Cauchy-Schartz inequality for $v,w \in V$ you have $\vert \langle v,w \rangle \vert \le \Vert v \Vert \Vert w \Vert$. Hence for $\Vert w \Vert =1$ you have $\vert \langle v,w \rangle \vert \le \Vert v \Vert$. Which proves that $\sup\{\vert \langle v,w \rangle \vert | \ w \in V, \ \Vert w \Vert =1\} \le \Vert w \Vert$

To prove the reverse inequality you know that $\Vert v \Vert^2=\langle v,v \rangle = \Vert v \Vert \langle v,\frac{v}{\Vert v \Vert} \rangle$ where $\frac{v}{\Vert v \Vert}$ is a vector with norm equal to $1$ in the case $v \neq 0$.

And the equality is trivial when $v = 0$.