# Norm Equals Supremum of Inner Product when ||w||=1?

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces, inner-products

Let $V$ be an inner product space, and $v\in V$. I want to show that $$||v||=\sup\{\langle\,v,w\rangle:||w||=1\}$$

What I know: 
Since this is a generic inner product, $||v||=\sqrt{\langle\,v,v\rangle}$. So, if $||v||=0$ then $v=0$. The equality is trivial if $v=0$, so I know I need to consider when $v\neq 0$. Also, we have that $||w||=1$ this implies that $w=\frac{v}{||v||}$ if we use it in terms of $v$.

I am not sure if I am pulling the correct information, but I am confused on how to proceed to prove the equality statement.

Comment: The idea is to prove that $\|v\| \le \sup\{\langle\,v,w\rangle:||w||=1\}$ and $\|v\| \ge \sup\{\langle\,v,w\rangle:||w||=1\}$. See [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1295407/norm-is-sup-of-inner-products-proof) for more details.

Comment: Thank you! The only part of the linked proof I don't understand is the 5th line. It follows from, "So we calculate." The equality statement there isn't clear to me. Could you explain? Specifically the inner part of the equality.

Comment: I got it! Thank you for the help and reference!