# I must prove that $\lVert z \rVert_H=\sup_{v\in H,\lVert v \rVert_H=1} |\langle v,z\rangle|.$

Tags: functional-analysis

let $(H,\langle \cdot,\cdot\rangle$ be a Hilbert space. I must prove that $$\lVert z \rVert_H=\sup_{v\in H,\lVert v \rVert_H=1} |\langle v,z\rangle|.$$
For $z=0$ it is trivially true. We suppose that $z\ne 0$.

I managed to show only the following:let $v\in H$ such that $\lVert v \rVert_H =1$, then by Cauchy Schwarz inequality we have $$|\langle v, z\rangle |\le \lVert v\rVert_H\cdot\lVert z \rVert_H=\lVert z\rVert_H$$ therefore $$\sup_{v\in H,\lVert v \rVert_H=1} |\langle v,z\rangle|\le \lVert z\lVert_H$$

Any suggestions for the other inequality?

Comment: Actually, it's true in any normed space $X$ that $||x||=\max\limits_{||f||=1} |f(x)|$ where $f\in X^*$. This is a corollary of the Hahn-Banach theorem. As for a Hilbert space, we know exactly what are the elements of $H^*$, they are given by the Riesz representation theorem.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1295407/norm-is-sup-of-inner-products-proof

Comment: $$|\langle z/\|z\|_H, z\rangle| \leq \sup_{\|v\|_H = 1} |\langle v, z\rangle|$$ Edit: typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $$|\langle z/||z||,z\rangle|=||z||, $$ also $||(z/||z||)||=1$, so $||z||\leq \operatorname{sup}_{||v||=1}|\langle v, z\rangle|$.