# The Gaussian width of the unit ball

Tags: probability-theory

The Gaussian width of a subset $T \subseteq\mathbb{R^n}$ is defined as follows.

$$w(T)=\mathbb{E} \hspace{0.04 in} \sup \langle g,x\rangle$$

where $g$ has the distribution $\mathcal N(0,I_{n})$ and the $\sup$ is taken over all $x$ in $T$.

Now, I want to show that

$$w(B_{1}^{n})= \mathbb{E}\ \lvert\lvert g \rvert\rvert_{2}$$

where $B_{1}^{n}$ is the unit ball.

I am not good at probability so my idea might be completely wrong. I tried to use Cauchy-Schwarz, but we should have the equality form of that inequality to get the result, and $g$ is a random vector so the linearly dependence of $g$ and $x$ is not meaningful, to my understanding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is well known that for any vector $g$,
$$\|g\|_2 = \sup\left\{\langle g,x\rangle, \|x\|_2 = 1\right\} \tag 1$$
This follows from Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, and you can find a proof [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1295407/norm-is-sup-of-inner-products-proof).

This implies immediately that
$$w(B_{1}^{n}):=\mathbb E\ \left[\sup\left\{\langle g,x\rangle, \|x\|_2 = 1\right\} \right]\stackrel{(1)}{=}  \mathbb{E}\ \lvert\lvert g \rvert\rvert_{2}. $$

Comment: Thank you so much. Also, that well-known fact was very useful, I did not know it. Just one thing, what happens if x is allowed to be inside the unit ball? Do we still have the same result? @Stratos supports the strike

Comment: Oh yeah if you have $\|x\|_2\le 1$ instead of $\|x\|_2=1$ the conclusion is the same, just look at the proof in the linked post and check that the same argument still works.

Answer (score 2):

$\sup_{\|x\|^2\leq 1}\langle g,x\rangle=\|g\|$ is an obvious fact and has nothing to do with probability: just consider the geometric interpretation of the scalar product. The next step $E(\|g\|) $ uses the $\chi_n^2$ law. It says that the distribution of $2\|g\|^2 $ is $\gamma(n/2).$ You get $$E(\|g\|) =\frac{\Gamma((n+1)/2)}{\sqrt{2}\Gamma(n/2)}.$$